# Manipulate ampersand in sed

Tags: sed, ampersand

Is it possible to manipulate the ampersand in sed? I want to add +1 to all numbers in a file. Something like this:

```
sed -i "s/[0-9]\{1,2\}/$(expr & + 1)/g" filename
```

*EDIT: Today I created a loop using grep and sed that does the job needed. But the question remains open if anyone knows of a way of manipulating the ampersand, since **this is not the first time I wanted to run commands on the replacement string, and couldn't**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed will need to thunk out to some shell command (with '!') on *each* line to do that.

Here you think you are calling sed which then calls back to the shell to evaluate *`$(expr & + 1)`* for each line, but actually it isn't. *`$(expr & + 1)`* will just get statically evaluated (once) by the outer shell, and cause an error, since '&' is not at that point a number.

To actually do this, either:

1. **[hardcode all ten cases of last digit 0..9, as per this example in sed documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Increment-a-number.html#Increment-a-number)**
2. Use a sed-command which starts with *'1,$!'* to invoke the shell on each line, and perform the increment there, with expr, awk, perl or whatever.
3. FOOTNOTE: I never knew about the [/e modifier](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command), which php-coder shows.

Comment: I don't get it! Something like this?    sed ''1,$!' s/[0-9]\{1,2\}/'$(expr & + 1)'/g' filename

Comment: I can't access a UNIX shell right now, you'll have to play around with it a little.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `e` modifier to achieve this:

```
$ cat test.txt
1
2
$ sed 's/^[0-9]\{1,2\}$/expr & + 1/e' test.txt
2
3
```

In this case you should construct command in replacement part which will be executed and result will be used for replacement.

Comment: Almost there! The file has not numbers only. It has also parentheses, so I get: sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Sorry for not explaining properly: contents are mixed: $vbx02->pack_start($hbx01);

Comment: Never knew about that! Was it always in _sed_?

Comment: @teresa-e-junior `e` should not work in this case. (IMHO a good idea is to show input data and desirable output to illustrate question.)

Comment: @php-coder most lines look like: `$vbx02->pack_start($hbx01);` and `$btn03 = GtkButton::new_from_stock(Gtk::STOCK_CANCEL);`

Comment: The `/e` modifier is in Perl, but not in all versions of sed.  For example, you don't get it in Mac OS X, at least not in Snow Leopard.  What version of Unix are you using?

Comment: @ray-toal Yes, it is a GNU extension. BTW, my code doesn't work when string contains not only numbers :(

Answer (score 1):

Great question. smci answered first and was spot on about shells.

In case you want to solve this problem in general, here is (for fun) a Ruby solution embedded in an example:

```
echo "hdf 4 fs 88\n5 22 sdf lsd 6" | ruby -e 'ARGF.each {|line| puts line.gsub(/(\d+)/) {|n| n.to_i+1}}'
```

The output should be

```
hdf 5 fs 89\n6 23 sdf lsd 7
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't have ruby installed! Not really worthy installing only for this!